# Rails/Unicorn error: can't read secret_key_base and secret_token from "config/secrets.yml"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

I use the following versions 
Unicorn 4.9
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.2.1
Nginx 1.4.6
Capistrano 3.4.0

When I deploy my application to production server and try to reach one of its pages I see an error in the unicorn.log file: "app error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)"

I've read tones of posts about the problems with unicorn and reading ENV variables, so I included those "missing" keys as constant values in `config/secrets.yml`:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secret_token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I still get the same error message, so it's probably not a unicorn+ENV variables issue.
Can you guess what happens here?

**Edit: the backtrace for this error**

```
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.297893 #26836] ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.298352 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.298592 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.298839 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.299089 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.299313 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.299550 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.299778 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.300011 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.300255 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.300490 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in `worker_loop'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.300722 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.300955 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:540:in `maintain_worker_count'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.301197 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.301506 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.301746 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
E, [2015-05-11T16:06:55.301962 #26836] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/MYAPP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

I've noticed that it goes to a directory named `ruby/2.2.0` although `ruby -v` shows ruby 2.2.1p85. Dows it make sense?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I stacked with the same

Comment: @ramusus 
Not yet, I skipped this task for now. Sorry.

Comment: I just solve it by restarting unicorn manually. My problem was capistrano didn't do it

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to have your actual secret keys in your secrets.yml file.

So, roll that back to the more secure version using environment variables.

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
etc.
```

Then add these two lines to the Unicorn environment config file **$/etc/default/unicorn**

```
# Application specific settings
export SECRET_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Kill and restart your Unicorn processes to get those environment variables loaded.

Comment: Security is not my issue here. I first want to get it work.
Anyway, it seems like I just needed to kill unicorn process, I was sure that capistrano deploy script does it.

Comment: By the way, setting those variables in `/etc/default/unicorn` doesn't work for me..

Comment: Then, I expect there's a problem in your config/unicorn_init.sh

Comment: or RVM or RVM path setup. As you know, there are a lot of moving parts. Your problem with the secret  keys is a hint to an underlying issue in one of the components.

Comment: Good luck ferreting it out. I hope my answer helps someone else. Pne ;ats thought, you can't just ignore security. You should fix this, and this is the fix, whenever you get the other problem(s) solved, you should come back and use the env vars, not hard coded passkeys in your secrets.yml file.

Comment: I'm sure I can't just ignore the security problem and it's not my plan. Actually that's my next step: to find out a way to use the ENV variables with unicorn. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -3):

Security should be a number one priority when deploying applications. I know it is hard, but security shouldn't be something you implement afterwards.

I've written a guide to help people deploy rails application securely with capistrano.

Setup is: Nginx + unicorn + zero downtime

Steps:

1. https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/1-setup.md
2. https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/2-deploy-setup.md
3. https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/3-app-deploy.md

It uses `dotenv-rails` to export environment variables and with the comment above you can securely use environment variables in your application where needed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The environment setup you created doesn't properly work, so I'm giving references on how it should be done with some best practices included.

Could you please clarify why this is bad answer, so I can adjust it accordingly.